# Regex url parameters

Tags: javascript

I don't no how regex works. but I have a url like:

http://localhost/BetaLeren/public/dashboard/general/video.php?video=13&time=19

but I want it that way:

http://localhost/BetaLeren/public/dashboard/general/video.php?video=13

How I can i do that with refex?
or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* you'll always have `video=` followed by `time=`, you could use the following regex:

```js
const link = 'http://localhost/BetaLeren/public/dashboard/general/video.php?video=13&time=19';

const updatedLink = link.match(/^.+video=\d+/)[0];

console.log(updatedLink);
```

`^` represents the beginning of the string.

`.+` represents any character 1 or more times.

`\d+` represents any digit 1 or more times.

Comment: thank you for your comment. it works now thx.